# Laravel: middleware check if user is softdeleted or not

Tags: laravel, soft-delete

I am using softdelete for users when a user is deleted.
When logging in or authenticating, all users are authenticated. So, I made a middleware named:

> isSoftdeletedorNot

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            if ($request->user()->deleted_at == null) :
                return $next($request);
            else:
                Auth::logout();
                Session::flush();
                Session::regenerate();
                return redirect()->route('login')->withErrors(['suspended' => 'Your account is deactivated']);
            endif;
        }
```

It executes well. The problem is the redirected route shows `404 error` and when I manually hard refresh it, it works again.

Comment: you are facing issue in redirect and your redirect route is  "login" right, please check if that route you have defined in your route.

Comment: Are you sure your soft-deleting is working?  Soft-deleted users should not be able to log in, if you are using standard Laravel auth stuff.  Do you have your own login controller/code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```php
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->user()->deleted_at != null) {
            Auth::logout();
            Session::flush();
            Session::regenerate();
            return redirect()->route('login')->withErrors(['suspended' => 'Your account is deactivated']);
        }else{
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why? What did you do, and why do you think that will help?  Explain your answer - code-only answers are considered low quality on SO.